# PHP array element calling a function?! $a=$b['c']($d,$e,$f);

Tags: php

Could someone please explain what is going on here in this code?

I can see it is an array called b accessing an element with the key 'c', but the stuff in the brackets? I don't know what is going on here.

```
$a=$b['c']($d,$e,$f);
```

Answer (score 3):

`$b['c']` must be a function name.

try to print it, you'll see.

```
$a=$b['c']($d,$e,$f);
```

calls that function passing `$d`, `$e` and `$f` arguments to it.

Try :

```
<?php

$func = 'var_dump';
$foo = array(1,2,3);
$func($foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking at a [variable function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

The expression above first evaluates the associative array `$a=$b['c']` and then calls the function with that name, passing the arguments `$d,$e,$f`.

From the description:

> PHP supports the concept of variable functions. This means that if a
>   variable name has parentheses appended to it, PHP will look for a
>   function with the same name as whatever the variable evaluates to, and
>   will attempt to execute it. Among other things, this can be used to
>   implement callbacks, function tables, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

It seems element at key `c` is expected to be a function.

In **PHP5**, you can use this kind of short notations. The function will be called with parameters d e and f.